# Algebra with all modules non-rigid

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Given a finite dimensional connected algebra $A$ with $Ext^{1}(M,M) \neq 0$ for any non-projective and non-injective module $M$.

1. Is $A$ selfinjective?
2. Is $A$ local?

Comment: You can probably guess my pedantic question about (2) ... :-)

Comment: I added "connected".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the path algebra of an $A_2$-quiver provides a counterexample. Let $M$ be a (finite dimensional) module. Then $M=S(1)^{n_1}\oplus S(2)^{n_2}\oplus P(1)^{n_3}$ where $S(1)=I(1)$ is injective non-projective and $S(2)=P(2)$ is projective non-injective. That $M$ is non-projective is thus equivalent to $n_1\neq 0$, the fact that $M$ is non-injective means that $n_2\neq 0$. But then $$\dim \operatorname{Ext}^1(M,M)=\dim \operatorname{Ext}^1(S(1)^{n_1},S(2)^{n_2})=n_1n_2\neq 0.$$

Comment: Thanks, I actually wanted to ask this question with M indecomposable but forgot this condition. I make a new thread. Here any indecomposable is projective or injective.